# How do I get the number pad on a usb keyboard working in Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard

My USB keyboard in Ubuntu Intrepid Linux has stopped working at all, and on any numpad keypress, will move the mouse cursor to the left side of the screen.

The same behaviour is present with numlock on or off.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I had same problem on Fedora 13 with Gnome Desktop. Same setting was toggled.

Answer (score 4):

In the Ubuntu menu bar, go to:

System > Preferences > Keyboard > Mouse Keys

Then uncheck "Pointer can be controlled using the keypad".

It seems on some Ubuntu update, this might have been enabled automatically.